# Is there a better "optional index signature" type in TypeScript than Partial<Record<Key, Value>>?

Tags: typescript

When I have a `const record: Record<string, number> = {}`, `record['a']` has type `number` even though it should really be `number | undefined`; the record doesn't and can't have *all* string properties.

So I tried

```
const partial_record: Partial<Record<string, number>> = {};
const y = partial_record['a'];
```

Now `y` is `number | undefined`, as I wanted. But there is another issue: `Object.entries(partial_record)` has type `[string, number | undefined][]`, though I expected `[string, number][]`; all properties that *are* present should have type `number`. This happens even with `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` (which I don't want to enable).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgU1HAJgLhgJSSVAeaOASzAHMAaGMAVwFsAjBOAPhgF4YBvAXwG4AoUJFgAPDDQZN28HKgDaAcgCGCgLoChEEABsEAOm0hSAChEBKXjAD0VqiFhKqdRnACE-QeGgwADkrhQREraAPqIyOgwAAr%20gcF42BEEUMRklBIuzKwcPBpesACe0n4BQaHhuCiKKurWthlSAD4w1GAoCABmJAgolEoQMO0QRIgonsIwAG7B1AgDHADy9ABWSFB6CGApRHPGJXHlsihmerRKPsbGciEA1ggFlNPas6pm7KxPsxb8NlMzczAIAALEDUbQoGCMJySOByVSUejUByIGDGBpwGDNVrtLpgHpmOH8IA)

Is there some type for partial records which combines my desired types for property access and `Object.entries` type?

And as a side issue: why does

```
const record: Record<string, number> = {};
const x: number = record['a'];
```

compile in the first place and are there compilation options which prevent it?

TypeScript version 5.1.6.

Comment: "*Why does it compile in the first place and are there compilation options which prevent it?*" - that's what [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) does

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! Wonder why it isn't part of `strict`...

Comment: IIRC it's very annoying with array indices which usually do exist when you access them

Comment: Then too bad there is no way to enable it for strings/symbols only.

Comment: …but you should just try it out. And tbh I don't really remember when I was using explicit array indexing last time, most often it's `for … of`, `arr.entries()`, `arr.map`, etc. So it might not actually be as annoying as I thought, or rather, have just the right annoyance factor where it matters to catch the mistakes.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, looks like we have only a few such cases in our codebase, and adding null assertions with an explanation isn't a problem at all. Thank you again!